# hamburger button color not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do i change the color of hamburger menu on css. Here is my attempt

```css
.hamburger-inner{
    background-color: white;
}




body{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/0aedeec9/dist/hamburgers.css" rel="stylesheet">



 <button class="hamburger hamburger--emphatic is-active" type="button" id="clickme">
                                <span class="hamburger-box">
                                    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                                </span>
                            </button>
```

Im trying to change the color from black to white. Any suggetions.

Comment: Hi, did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the color using the following CSS

```
    .hamburger-box .hamburger-inner,
    .hamburger-box .hamburger-inner::before,
    .hamburger-box .hamburger-inner::after {
        background-color: white;
    }
```

```css
.hamburger-box .hamburger-inner,
.hamburger-box .hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-box .hamburger-inner::after {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/0aedeec9/dist/hamburgers.css" rel="stylesheet">



<button class="hamburger hamburger--emphatic is-active" type="button" id="clickme">
                                <span class="hamburger-box">
                                    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                                </span>
                            </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the background color to the pseudo-elements before and after like this

```
.hamburger--emphatic.is-active .hamburger-inner::before {
background-color: white;
}

.hamburger--emphatic.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-inner::after {
    background:#fff;
}
```